# How to avoid multiple do try catch statements in Swift

Tags: swift

I was creating some code and I find a problem that can escalate quickly on my do try catch.

This is my code in Swift:

```
    do {
        let sendResponseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(SendResponseModel.self, from: data)
        redirectUserToScreen1(sendResponseModel)
    } catch {
        dprint("first catch")
        do {
            let sendAnotherResponseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(SendAnotherResponseModel.self, from: data)
            redirectUserToScreen2(sendAnotherResponseModel)
        }
        catch {
            dprint("second catch")
        }
    }
```

I got a http json response that becomes Data , but it comes from different sources in this case. I will need to create more "try JSONDecoder().decode".

Is that possible to create some type of code to not create a nested "do try catch" statements?

Comment: If you don't care about the errors that are thrown, use `try?` instead of `try`. You get an optional, so you can do a `if let ... else if let ...` structure.

Comment: Or use separate methods.

Comment: Hint: you should care about errors!

Comment: The answer depends, does your handling logic need to be different between the two cases?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use the @Sweeper idea to create the code below

```
    if let sendPixResponseModel: SendPixResponseModel = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SendPixResponseModel.self, from: data) 
    {
        dprint("sendPixResponseModel: \(sendPixResponseModel)")
        GetBancoByISPB(sendPixResponseModel.recebedor.ispb)
    }
    else if let SendPixBranchAgencyAndAccountResponseModel: SendPixBranchAgencyAndAccountResponseModel = try?  JSONDecoder().decode(SendPixBranchAgencyAndAccountResponseModel.self, from: data)
    {
        dprint("SendPixBranchAgencyAndAccountResponseModel: \(SendPixBranchAgencyAndAccountResponseModel)")
        
        ComprovanteStaticValues.setDataOnComprovante(SendPixBranchAgencyAndAccountResponseModel)
        dprint("SendPixBranchAgencyAndAccountResponseModel: \(SendPixBranchAgencyAndAccountResponseModel)")
    }
```

Comment: Muting errors is a very bad practice! What you actually should do in a `catch` clause is to _handle_ the error and potentially _revert_ the half done side effects in the `do` clause. If you cannot or do not want to handle the error, pass it to the calling function. Eventually, some upper layer should handle it - even if this is just presenting it to the user. Should we blame @sweeper?  ;)

Comment: I **strongly** advise against using `try?`. You'll be amazed at just how many questions we see coming through here, all along the lines of "my code just silently doesn't work, and I don't know why.", only to discover that there was a thrown error (with plenty of actionable debugging information), which the author unintentionally discarded with `try?`. Sometimes that's what you want, but use it cautiously.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of how you design you code. To simplify, here's a stripped example from yur question:

```swift
func doSomething() throws {
    // ...
}

func doSomethingElse() throws {
    // ...
}

func consumeThrowables() {
    do {
        try doSomething()
    } catch {
        do {
            try doSomethingElse()
        } catch {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

One option would be to extract a separate method to handle errors:

```swift
func consumeThrowables() {
    do {
        try doSomething()
    } catch {
        handleErrors()
    }
}

func handleErrors() {
    do {
        try doSomethingElse()
    } catch {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Another option would be to design a chain of throwing calls differently, for example:

```swift
func consumeConsumer() {
    do {
        try consumeThrowables()
    } catch {
        // ...
    }
}

func consumeThrowables() throws {
    do {
        try doSomething()
    } catch {
        try doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

The possibilities are really limited only to your imagination.

Comment: thanks for your idea, I'll consider it